# How To Display Product Brand Name In Left Column In Product Page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, column

I want to display a product brand name in left column of product page. Can you help me to solve this ?

Thanks advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `local.xml` and put this code:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.brandname" as="product_brandname" template="catalog/product/brandname.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Now create new template file `brandname.phtml` at

```
\app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_THEME\template\catalog\product\brandname.phtml
```

Add this code in `brandname.phtml`

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php 
    /* YOU CAN GET ANY PRODUCT ATTRIBUTE HERE. */
    echo $_product->getBrand(); 
?>
```

Note: Change `echo $_product->getBrand();` as per your **BRAND attribute code**

Comment: My attribute code is [manufacturer]. Then i want to call  echo $_product->getmanufacturer(); ?

Comment: i followed that code it will return nothing.

Comment: I'm sure , you missed some steps. Have you changed to `echo $_product->getManufacturer();` ?

Comment: i tried this echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'); it will working. Now i want to add a link to that brand name, What to do? this link goes to all the product related to that brand name

Comment: It's hard to show here coz it's a different question, please raise a new one, I'll show solution there, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('brand');?>
```