# How to call a product attributes in magento left column of product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute

I want to display product attribute in product page left column, when I try this code :

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('your_attribute_code');
```

It is returning fatal error. Can you guide me how to solve this?

Comment: post your error

Comment: Try this echo $_product->getYoutAttributeCode()

Comment: which block you have used ? and where you have added this code ?

Comment: i am used directly in 2 col left.phtml  [left column part]

Comment: it's already solved here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116344/how-to-display-product-brand-name-in-left-column-in-product-page

Comment: Upload screen shot.what type of fatal error. 

Is that error calling method on Non Object coming ????

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace from  `$this->getProduct()` to `Mage::registry('current_product')`

For exp. I am calling product description attribute here replace it with yours :

```
 <?php $_description = Mage::registry('current_product')->getDescription(); ?>
<?php if ($_description): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></h2>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute(Mage::registry('current_product'), $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```